# Why is my for loop not progressing to the nested for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I wrote a nested for-loop in C, however I have run into a problem where the for loop does not continue past the printf statement and into the other for-loop.

```
for(x = 5; x<=100; x=x+5)
        printf("\n");
        for(y = 5; y<=100; y=y+5)
            printf("%6.2f |", ((pow(x,4)/pow(y,2))+sqrt(y)));

        printf("\n");
```

The for loop will just print out the newline character 20 times and then spit out a bunch of numbers at the end. I am used to writing in Python so I assume I am messing something up quite badly.Here is the output after the 20 blank lines

```
4862027.24 |1215509.41 |540228.87 |303881.03 |194486.00 |135061.73 |99230.92 |75975.47 |60031.71 |48627.32 |40189.44 |33771.81 |28777.44 |24814.6
2 |21617.66 |19001.23 |16832.84 |15015.74 |13477.96 |12165.06 |
```

Comment: Hint: You will need some `{` and `}`.

Comment: In Python, indentations are part of the language, but not in C. Those loops may look nested, but they aren't.

Comment: @pzaenger Thank you, I totally forgot those. Still trying to get used to C coming from python.

Comment: Good practice is to have ` { }` for every loop you intended to use.  this makes sure that you know which part of code get executed for any condition .

Comment: @makdu it depends what style you adhere to and is a matter of preference, but for a beginner I'd definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike with Python, white space doesn't matter in c. Unlike Ruby, you actually need to use brackets for loops.

```
for(x = 5; x<=100; x=x+5) {
        printf("\n");
        for(y = 5; y<=100; y=y+5) {
            printf("%6.2f |", ((pow(x,4)/pow(y,2))+sqrt(y)));
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I feel so dumb now totally forgot those.

Comment: @Liam87 NP. It totally happened to me the other day while using Javascript after writing in Ruby for a couple weeks.

Answer (score 0):

you do know that a block statement, like `for`, without braces, will only execute the first following statement.

The main problem with the posted code is it is missing a set of braces,.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop without braces will execute the next line only.